# Custom Data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

How to create custom data grid in wpf. All row,column header and cells contains  check box.Below is the structure.[image]

I have done this coding, however its impacting performance in case of more number of row and column .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific and post some code, without seeing what you have we cant really comment on why your performance is poor, and I''d guess this will get closed pretty quickly

Comment: 1st i have creating rows,columns and then creating cells.